# Can we update transactionSecurity Policy using rest api or meta data api?

Tags: metadata-api, apexrest

Can we update transactionSecurity Policy using rest api or meta data api ?i tried with rest api,its not supporting updation and in meta data its throwing unknwn type.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! It's good to hear that you have tried to address your issue on your own prior to posting your question. If you're encountering an error message, it's a good idea to include the entire text of the error message **verbatim** (that is, word-for-word. Do not try to paraphrase or make the error shorter). If you haven't already, I'd suggest looking through the documentation on the REST and Metadata APIs to see if support for this object is explicitly mentioned. Looking through the SOAP API documentation for objects is also a good resource for seeing whether something can be edited.

Comment: One last note. Generally speaking, the more details you include, and the more you can show that you've researched or attempted to overcome your issue on your own, the better your question will be received. It's possible, but very hard, to include too many details, and details are what helps other people identify issues and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Bhaskar,

TransactionSecurityPolicy is supported by the metadata API and can be migrated over. Check out: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_transactionsecurity.htm

Make sure that your package.xml is setup the right way. I have found the "Unknown type" only when there is a typo in the types element in package.xml

Good luck!

Sridhar

Comment: Yes,there is type calles customapexpolicy coming from responce so there is no field in metadadata api,thats why unable to updating

Comment: You get a new type introduced in the response? Can you place your package.xml request and response here? I might be able to help better with that.